Why all the Environment Variables inside my Dev environment got their Export checkbox set to Yes, although i set them to No last month?
last month , i went to all the environment variables inside my Dev environment's solution and i set their Export checkbox to No.Those environment variables are referencing SharePoint lists/libraries and SharePoint sites.
but today i check those settings since i added a new environment variable, and i noted that all the solution environment variables inside my Dev environment have their Export checkbox set to Yes, as follow:-

any advice why those were changed automatically for me? now i want to set them to No, because i want to export the solution from Dev to PROD environment. any advice why this happened and how i can avoid this in the future? and did anyone face this issue recently ?
Also i unchecked those yesterday >> do the export >> but today all the checkboxes are checked again!!
